# No module named pytube found

Tags: python, installation, module, pip, pytube

So I've already seen that I need to do something like `pip install pytube` and ive already done that but when I run my code, I see a "no module named "Pytube" found" error. When I use `pip install pytube` in my terminal, it says that the installation was complete, but I still am getting the error. Idk if this is a dumb mistake or something deeper but any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

probably would be easy if you show the code, but maybe you are writing "Pytube" instead of "pytube", or maybe you are executing your code in the wrong environment.

Comment: I dont think that you are using environments, but you can create a "different" python of your main python to install libraries and not installing all your libraries in the main python folder, you can read more about this here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/a-complete-guide-to-python-virtual-environments/

Comment: heres the code ```from pytube import YouTube

link = input("link: ")
yt = YouTube(link)

video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
video.download()```

Comment: I tested your code, and it seems work fine. You could check if the library appears when you execute "pip list" on the console

Comment: is this right?
 pytube            12.1.0
pytube3           9.6.4
typing_extensions 4.3.0

Comment: In my case, it just appears the 12.1.0 version, maybe you could try with "pytube3" instead of "pytube" because seems that you have two versions of pytube

Comment: Tried it, nothing

Comment: If you are using VS code, you could show us the screen and execute pip list on the terminal to have some more information.

Comment: i edited the original post to include a photo